# React Junior Developer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, frontend

I want to display the title in an array format so that it can be seen in the UI. But I am not sure how to use JSX syntax.

```
const { data: CartData, error: CartError } = useSWR(`http://localhost:3060/user/Carts`, fetcher)
```

console.log(CartData)

```
Object
email: alstntorl@naver.com
id: 1
Cartd: Array(4)
0: {id: 1, 
Title: 나이키 x 앰부쉬 덩크  딥 로얄 블루, 
 …}
1: {id: 11, 
Title: 뉴발란스 2002R 그레이, 
 …}
2: {id: 34, Title: 컨버스 하이크 하이 블랙 화이트 검,, …}
3: {id: 36, Title: 아디다스 이지 부스트 380 미스트, 10, …}
length: 4
```

First, I imported the Title in an array format using the map function.

```
    let Title = CartData?.Carted?.map((list) => list.Title);
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to map single element in order to display in jsx. You can map array, but it still need to have 1 root.

```js
function MyComponent() {
const { data: CartData, error: CartError } = 
  useSWR(`http://localhost:3060/user/Carts`, fetcher)

  return <div>{CartData?.Carted?.map((item) => <div key={item.Title}> {item.Title} {item.Price} {item.Cintents} </div>)}</div>
}
```

Comment: Just attach it to the div, but it was stupid. Thanks.

Comment: @김민수 does it solve your problem?

Comment: `    const renderItems = () => (
      CartData?.Cartd?.map((list, index) => (
        <tr key={index}>
          <td>
            {list.Title}
          </td>
        </tr>
      ))
 `  {renderItems} I tried to print it out, but it doesn't respond.

Comment: Actually, I want to print out the Price Name as well as the Title.

Comment: @김민수do not use index as key. It will be perf issue. I updated answer, if you show data structure of CartData, I can answer more accurate.

Comment: `Cartd: Array(4)
0: {id: 1, Title: "나이키 x 앰부쉬 덩크  딥 로얄 블루", Contents: "윗부분이 커팅된 텅과 끝부분이 입체적으로 구현되어 신발의 뒤쪽까지 넘어가게 되는 스우시 로…하이 제품과는 달리 움푹 파인 뒷부분과 힐탭에 'AMBUSH'가 새겨진 것이 특징인 제품", Price: "199.000", ShoesNames: "4", …}
1: {id: 11, Title: "뉴발란스 2002R 그레이", Contents: "뉴발란스 힙한 신발!", Price: "99.000", ShoesNames: "7", …}
2: {id: 34, Title: "컨버스 하이크 하이 블랙 화이트 검", Contents: "엉청 이쁩니다. 추천드려요", Price: "112.000", ShoesNames: "8", …}
3: {id: 36, Title: "아디다스 이지 부스트 380 미스트", Contents: "봄에 인기 많았던 신발.", Price: "213.000", ShoesNames: "10", …}
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)

id: 1

Comment: I want to print Price Title Contents. I'm trying to create a shopping cart page!

Comment: I updated answer. Let me know if you have any issues

Comment: There are no errors and it is not displayed in the UI Thanks for responding.

Comment: If not, I will express it like this: map(title), map(price).

Comment: fir debug purposes, I usually put JSON.stringify inside the JSX. f.e. <div> {JSON.stringify(CartData?.Carted)}  {CartData?.Carted?.map((item) => <div key={item.Title}> {item.Title} {item.Price} {item.Contents} {JSON.stringify( item)}</div>)}</div> In this case you may see what inside ur variables and where chain is broken.

Comment: It runs fine. Thank you for answering to the end

Comment: `productinfo
Brand: "1"
Carts: [{…}]
Cody: "1"
Comments: Array(1)
0:
ProductId: 37
User:
id: 1
regid: "alstn"`

Comment: `<p>{productinfo?.Comments?.User?.map((list) => list.regid)}</p>`  If there is an array of 3, can we do something like this?

Answer (score -1):

You need to write the component to render the result like this:

```
const CardDetails = ({ fetcher }) => {
  const { data, error } = useSWR(`http://localhost:3060/user/Carts`, fetcher)

  // render error/empty states
  if (error) return <div>Failed to load cart</div>
  if (!data) return <div>Loading cart...</div>

  // return the result
  return (
    <div>
      {
        data.carted.map((item) => <span key={item.id}>{item.title}</span>
      }
    </div>
  )
}

// later render the component to the DOM
ReactDOM.render(
  <CardDetails />,
  document.getElementById("root")``
);
```